# Define a relationship without actually creating foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table for which I have changed the MySQL engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.  This is the only table that has been changed, the tables related to it still use MyISAM.

```
class Signals(Base, sql_functions):
    __tablename__ = 'Signals'

    def __init__(self, message_id=None, clip_id=None, signal_id=None):
        self.message_id = message_id
        self.clip_id = clip_id
        self.signal_id = signal_id

    __table_args__ = {  
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',  
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'  
    }

    __mapper_args__= {'always_refresh': True}

    id = Column(Integer(10), primary_key=True)
    message_id = Column(Integer(10), ForeignKey('Messages.id'))
    clip_id = Column(Integer(10), ForeignKey('Clips.id'))
    signal_id = Column(Integer(10), ForeignKey('Signal_names.id'), primary_key=True)

    sig_name = relationship("SignalNames", backref=backref('Signals', order_by=id), primaryjoin = 'Signals.signal_id == SignalNames.id', foreign_keys='SignalNames.id')
    clips = relationship("Clips", backref=backref('Signals', order_by=id), primaryjoin='Signals.clip_id == Clips.id', foreign_keys='Clips.id')
    messages = relationship("Messages", backref=backref('Signals', order_by=id), primaryjoin='Signals.message_id == Messages.id', foreign_keys='Messages.id')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Signals ('%s %s %s')>" % (self.message_id, self.clip_id)

    Index('idx_msg_id', Signals.message_id)
```

Since I have changed the Engine to InnoDB the foreign keys are being created, which is not desired.  The problem is that SQLAlchemy is using the foreign key definitions to define the relationship joins.

Is there a way to prevent the creation of the foreign keys, or to define the relationships without the adding the foreign keys?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the creation of foreign keys?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, because any of tables connected are myIsam and I cant change them furthermore This table is huge and I'm using Partitions and you can use partitions when you have FK defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from another forum -

instead of 
    `join(clips_table.Clips)`
I have used 
    `join(signals_table.Signals.clips)`

Answer (score 1):

When creating a relationship, SQLAlchemy uses `ForeignKey`s to detect which columns to join on.  You can of course [override that with whatever join condition you want](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#creating-custom-foreign-conditions).  You're almost doing that already, you just need to remove the `ForeignKey` from each column and correctly define the foreign column for each relationship.

```
signal_id = Column(Integer(10), primary_key=True)

sig_name = relationship(
    'SignalNames',
    primaryjoin='Signals.signal_id == SignalNames.id',
    foreign_keys='Signals.signal_id',
    remote_side='SignalNames.id',
)
```

---

<sub>Typically, though, you want to use foreign keys.</sub>